# Appending results to vector in a for loop in R

Tags: r, function, append

I want to find column names in the data set x and if the column name is in data frame y, I want to append the row indices to a vector:

```
store <- c() # vector
check_same_colnames<-function(x,y) {
  for (i in colnames(x)) {
    if (i %in% colnames(y)) {
      store<-append(store,which(colnames(x) == i))
      print(i)
    }
  }
}
```

But after I run this, store gets `NULL`

Comment: Put `return(store)` at the end of your function

Comment: I think you could also replace the complicated for-if structure of the function with just `which(colnames(x) %in% colnames(y))`

Comment: Could you post some sample data? Also, you mention that the row indices in a vector, shouldn't it be the column indices?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I came up with, if I understand the problem correctly. I created some sample data to show the process.

```
##Creating fake data
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(2)
x <- bind_cols(lapply(1:7, function(i)sample(1:1000,100)))
y <- bind_cols(lapply(1:7, function(i)sample(1:1000,100)))


##Changing column names of second dataset
colnames(y) <- c("V1", "V2","V33", "V4", "V5", "V66","V7")


##Setting up a combination of regex and sapply

columns_found <- unlist(sapply(colnames(x), function(i)grep(paste0("^",i,"$"),colnames(y),value = FALSE)))
```

Basically, what the last line does is that it uses sapply to pass a function that checks if there is a regex match in the columns of y. I use unlist because it otherwise ,will return a list.